# Mapping & Scaffolding Many-to-Many Relation with extra column - Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

I'm trying to mapping and scaffolding many-to-many relation with Spring Roo.

For example, I have two column: Product and Order with the many-to-many relationship.

So I need to create an intermediate table such as ProductOrder, with some extra column, for example, OrderDate.

So my mapping class will look like this:

```
...
@RooJpaActiveRecord(identifierType = **ProductOrderId**.class)
public class ProductOrder {
    private Date OrderDate;
}
```

The **ProductOrderId** class will look like this:

```
...
@RooIdentifier
public final class ProductOrderId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product_id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Order order_id;

}
```

After that, I ran this command in Roo Shell to scaffolding views:

```
web mvc scaffold --class ...
```

But the scaffolded views just show two text fields for Order Id and Product Id, it **should show a Combobox** which I can select and **it cannot insert to the database.**

I've searched for a while on the internet, but seem likes there is no solution.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the new Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3, it solves a lot of problems related to entity relationships.

In your case, now the Select2 component is used to select the related entity.

Visit the project page at http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/ to download it.

Note that a Milestone version generate artifacts that could change in newer versions, but it could affect your project or not depending on your needs.

May the Force be with you.

Comment: Thank! May the force be with you. I'll try the new one!